# Ruby field_with_errors doesn't @extend .control-group .error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Ok. I can't figure this out. The problem is that `@extend` is not working in css. I have css:

```
@import "bootstrap";

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}
```

It doesn't highlight the fields that have div class `.field_with_errors`. I can't figure out why, it worked on other apps I made. If I write in CSS something like `color: #f00;` - this works. It just doesn't `@extend` for some reason. Any ideas?

Form:

```
<h1>Report</h1>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@problem) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name, raw("Your name:") %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email, raw("E-mail address (for confirmation):") %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :description, raw("Enter a description of the problem:") %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>

      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Probably a dumb question, I must've missed something. I just don't know what it is and would really like this to work like it did before. Any help appreciated!

**Edit:**
After looking at bootstrap-sass files, I realized that I am able to @extend classes that are in the files there (`@extend .form-control` works for instance). So it must be that `.error` and `.control-group` is not there!! Where it went I still can't figure out, unless they just changed it like a week ago. :/

Comment: `@extend` is for SASS, aka `scss` files. Does your CSS file end in `.scss`?

Comment: Yes, the file is custom.css.scss

Comment: Maybe if I can figure out where these classes are defined (.error and .control-group). It's like they're not defined or they're failing to get imported somehow. Sass works, I tested by creating a class and extending it in another class.

Comment: `.control-group` is not in Bootstrap 3, it's replaced with `.form-group` and `.error` is not part of Bootstrap, it's probably defined in the scaffolding css but you're perhaps not including that now or in the right order?

Comment: What is the scaffolding css?

Comment: When you run `rails generate scaffold MyController` it will make some base css for you, which I believe includes a `.error` class. I think the issue is as you've stated – you can't extend things that don't exist. `.control-group` isn't in bootstrap 3 and `.error` might not be defined either if you're not using the scaffolded css or did not scaffold any controllers in the first place. I'm assuming you're using rails by the HTML snippet but maybe you're not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ruby on rails (I think I tagged it but someone removed). So you're saying since I didn't do any scaffolding these classes don't exist. I guess I don't remember scaffolding before, but it did give me those classes. So you solved my problem, thanks a lot! If you put it as answer I can mark correct or something. Thank you!

Comment: It does look different then the one in Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial for example. I wonder why that is.

Comment: Also .error class was not created in scaffolding. They have css for .field_with_errors and #error_explanation. So it must be coming from somewhere else, I assume bootstrap cause I can't think of another possibility. I found .control-group.error class in sample_app, I think I'm getting close to the source of this problem.

Comment: Ok. so I just solved the problem. It is weird though, because I don't know the cause of the problem! I changed 2 things, first I put bootstrap-sass gem before sass-rails in gemfile which didn't seem to change anything. Then when I moved the .field_with_errors class in css file to the beginning of the file it worked! And when I moved it back to its original place it continues working. Weird. :/ Well it works lol

Comment: I don't think I could write out a good solution but if you can, write your own answer and accept it so the questions marked answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This has to do with Twitter-Bootstrap, which has a class `.alert` in it. That is the class responsible for showing errors with correct styling.
Bootstrap installs who knows where and is easiest to access through Developer Tools in browser (that sucks). I couldn't find where the source of the gem is located (it pointed me to folder that is not a folder). So I copied twitter css files from github directly into my app -> vendor/assets/stylesheets . Now I can deal with the problem.
I changed the style of .alert class inside one of bootstrap files (`_alerts.scss`) and added extra classes in my `custom.css.scss` file to make border around inputs red on errors.
Somehow this whole thing worked better in previous apps I made, I think this has to do with changes they made to bootstrap and possibly the fact that I messed with bootstrap's original design (like a full-width header).
The biggest thing that led me to solution was that the class is `.alert` and not `.error` like I thought. Also big thanks to browser developer tools, I couldn't find my files without you.

**Edit**:
Here's the download instructions on Bootstrap to get the files:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Comment: Sorry, but this is really going in the wrong direction. I have posted a new answer that reflects the changes of class names in Bootstrap 3. Your solution actually kind of reverts Bootstrap 3 back to Bootstrap 2 in this regard.

Comment: So you don't use the bootstrap gem but just the css files in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`? That is an option if you want to directly alter the bootstrap files. However, if you address the correct classes in `custom.css.scss` there is no need for that. It is much more convenient and 'rails-like' to use the gem. I also think that almost all users facing the given error message will have the same proplem: using bootstrap 2 code for bootstrap 3 gem. They should just install the correct gem version or alter their code. Redefining classes like you suggest is not a proper answer to that error message.

Comment: Or one could put it like this: you are going the wrong direction. Instead of using styles of old bootstrap versions and then forcing them back into the bootstrap source you should use what is already there and just call the correct styles.

Comment: Allright, that is a valid point. I see why it may be preferable installing it that way. What I tried to illustrate is, that this just isn't necessary. It is a little bit overkill :-) Problem: Trying to highlight `.field_with_errors` raises error message. Solution: Change 3 lines of code in accordance with Bootstrap 3 class names. Whether you use the gem or not is not crucial here. But of course it is helpful that you pointed out an alternative way of implementing bootstrap.

Comment: Just because the solution is short doesn't make it better. I'm glad that I follow my answer here, because I had this and related problems more than once in different projects, and this solution solves all of them.

Answer (score 24):

As the comment of 'soup' points out, the problem is caused by installing Bootstrap 3 and then calling Bootstrap 2 class names. The class names have changed (have a look [here](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#cheat-cheat)). The correct code is:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

And accordingly the error message has to be wrapped in (also look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)):

```
div class="alert alert-danger"
```

So in your `app\views\shared\_error_messages.html.erb`-partial (you're propably reusing code from Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial) change `div class="alert alert-error"` to `div class="alert alert-danger"`. Because your code is so far off, I give you a version adapted for Bootstrap 3:

```
<h1>Report</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= form_for(@problem) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, raw("Your name:") %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email, raw("E-mail address (for confirmation):") %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :description, raw("Enter a description of the problem:") %>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the solution I posted below is better.

Comment: There are more people running into this problem than I expected, so I polished my answer a little bit. @Christiano: I don't really understand what you mean. If you use that tutorial, you should use the code that is mentioned there. I only referenced it because the OP apparently reused code from it. If you also want to do this, you have to install the correct gem (like `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'`) and change all the class names to Bootstrap 3.

Comment: +1, thanks! This should definitely be a correct answer! Works great for me.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone lands on this (like I did) because it isn't working with LESS, here's what I had to do:

```
.field_with_errors .form-control {
  &:extend(.has-error .form-control);
}

.field_with_errors .form-control:focus {
  &:extend(.has-error .form-control:focus);
}
```

When I tried it with:

```
.field_with_errors {
  &:extend(.has-error);
}
```

which is the equivalent of the recommended way I found to use the bootstrap 3 style for errors, LESS wasn't doing anything. It may have something to do with the fact that the selectors in bootstrap 3 that mention has-error always have it combined with something else, e.g.:

```
.has-error .form-control {
```

Anyway - the above solution worked for me so hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: That is a strange behavior. I don't know why that happens, but for Rails applications it is usually the most painfree approach to use SASS. You should consider using the Bootstrap-SASS-Gem: http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be working for me either, but I feel like I'm headed in the right direction. So here's an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading your code as per 3.x should work

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error causes because in application.scss there is the folowing line

```
*= require_tree .
```

and it is placed before the *@import "bootstrap"*.

So, *_custom.scss* has been included before Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to fix it -- what worked for me -- is to add `!optional` to both classes:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group !optional;
  @extend .error !optional;
}
```

Comment: Actually, adding `!optional` is not a fix of the mentioned problem - this is just the way to suppress errors in case if `.error` etc. can not be extended.

Answer (score -1):

OK, after chasing down this issue for a couple days, I figured out what the problem is.

You need to include bootstrap at the top your custom.css.scss file.

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

My guess would be that this includes all the classes in the custom file so that you can reference them later. I assume if you use some bootstrap gem it will make them globally available, but if you do it vanilla like I did then you need to use the code above.

Comment: Not relevant to this question:  the OP is importing the necessary file.